# Retrieve data from corrupted Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

After a system crash, MongoDB (4.0.6) refuses to start because of corrupted data. `Mongod --repair` does not fix it:

> WT_CURSOR.search_near: read checksum error for 24576B block at offset
>   57344: block header checksum of 3933356853 doesn't match expected
>   checksum

[full log](https://controlc.com/72632df7)

I'm not able to execute a mongodump because Mongod refuses to start.

How to retrieve data from collection files (collection-101--1569900909144710.wt)?

Comment: MongoDB support finally manages to rebuild the DB in few hours